# why my http post method is not accepting xml characters?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asmx

here is the function:

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e1)
    {

        string requestText = string.Format("strXMLData={0}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("<tag1>text</tag1>", e));

       string data = "strXMLData=%3c&strXMLFileName=text1.xml";  //Working I am //getting in service mathod <

string data = "strXMLData=%3e&strXMLFileName=text1.xml";  //Working I am getting in service mathod >

//string data = "strXMLData=%3c%3e&strXMLFileName=text1.xml"; //this is also working,I am getting in service mathod  
//string data = "strXMLData=%3ct%3e&strXMLFileName=text1.xml"; //this is not working,I am getting error 500, service mathod should revcive either same string or <t>
        byte[] dataStream = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(data);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:52995/MyWebService.asmx/ReceiveXMLByContent");
        request.Method = "POST";
      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
       // request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";

        request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string dataReturn = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

in above code I have written 3 cases from which two are working and 3rd  case

```
string data = "strXMLData=%3ct%3e&strXMLFileName=text1.xml"; //this is not working,I am getting error 500, service mathod should revcive either same string or <t>
```

is not working can you explain why it is not passing xml string, I am trying to pass

```
<tag1>
value
</tag1>
```

As we cannot pass xml without encoding so I encoded this string using

```
  string requestText = string.Format( System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("<tag1>text</tag1>", e)); //which returns %3ctag1%3etext%3c%2ftag1%3e
```

can you explain how to pass xml string..?
without getting error 500

here is web service method

```
  [WebMethod]
  public string ReceiveXMLByContent(string strXMLData, string strXMLFileName)
    {
        string b = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strXMLData);            
        return "worked";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem always lies in the following lines

```
        byte[] dataStream = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(data);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:52995/MyWebService.asmx/ReceiveXMLByContent");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
```

Make sure the request.ContentType is especially proper, like in this syntax:

```
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"; action=\"HeaderName\";";
```

Make sure you use try and catch method like this:

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e1)
 {
   string GetHttpPost = string.Empty;
   GetHttpPost = CallHTTPPostMethod(); 
 }

 public string CallHTTPPostMethod()
 {
   try
   {
     //Your code

     return YourResponseXMLInStringFormat;
   }
   catch(Exception wex)
   {
     string pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
     return pageContent;
   } 
  }
```

Comment: Can you write sample function for passing simple xml string to web method eg. <tag1>value</tag1>, for above scenario